# Census API did not provide data for selected endyear

Tags: r

Looking to pull in 2014 ACS data released recently through the `acs` package. Used the following basic query:

```
# Set the geo marker for all TN counties
geo <- geo.make(state = "TN", county = "*")
# Fetch Total Population for all TN counties
acs.fetch(endyear = 2014, span = 5, geography = geo, table.number = "B01003")
```

Output (shortened) is what I would expect to see for the 2010-2014 Total Population table:

```
ACS DATA: 
 2010 -- 2014 ;
  Estimates w/90% confidence intervals;
  for different intervals, see confint()
                             B01003_001  
Anderson County, Tennessee   75346 +/- 0 
Bedford County, Tennessee    45660 +/- 0 
Benton County, Tennessee     16345 +/- 0
```

But I also get this Warning, which is odd since the values for my `acs.fetch` match if I do a look-up in the [ACS FactFinder website](http://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/14_5YR/B01003/0400000US47.05000):

```
Warning messages:
1: In acs.fetch(endyear = 2014, span = 5, geography = geo, table.number = "B01003") :
  As of the date of this version of the acs package
  Census API did not provides data for selected endyear
2: In acs.fetch(endyear = endyear, span = span, geography = geography[[1]],  :
  As of the date of this version of the acs package
  Census API did not provides data for selected endyear
```

Am I misunderstanding something here? How can I be seeing the correct values, but the Warning Messages are telling me the Census API is not providing data for my parameters? Thank you.

Comment: `if (endyear < 2010 |  endyear > 2012)` is in the source code for the most recent version of the package. Prbly best to e-mail the maintainer eglenn@mit.edu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the developer, Ezra Glenn (eglenn@mit.edu):

The above is essentially correct: the data is getting fetched just fine.  The warning is outdated, from a time before the 2014 data was available.  (Technically it's not an error -- just a warning message to possibly explain what went wrong if the data did *not* get fetched.  In this case, it can be safely ignored.  I'll remove this in the next version.)